# How to set up T with Base Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, generic-list

I have two classes/controllers inheriting from a BaseController

```
public class ProductController : BaseController
public class CategoryController : BaseController
```

Considering these controllers are for individual pages, i need to format a `List/IEnumerable` of the object (Category or Product), passed in.

In the `BaseController` class i tried to add a `T` type but i cant understand how this should be done as the below code either throws errors that T does not exist or the existing Controllers break, if i add T as part of the class declaration `BaseController<T>`.

Heres the `BaseController` with the method to carry out this

```
public class BaseController : SomeController
{
    public List<string> GetDataRefresh(List<T> itemList) // <T> causes an error
    {
        foreach (var item in itemList)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

So i would like to pass in something like a list of products or categories, this method does the work with the data passed in and returns a list of the same data in a `List<string>` whether that be product, category or any other type.

How could i declare a T in this instance?

**Edit 1**

Once the above is working in this manner then in my ProductsController i should be able to do something like

```
private List<string> RefreshData()
{
   return GetDataRefresh(_ctx.GetProducts()); // GetProducts is List<Product>
}
```

In the Category Controller it would be

```
private List<string> RefreshData()
{
   return GetDataRefresh(_ctx.GetCategories()); // GetCategories is List<Category>
}
```

Comment: `public List<string> GetDataRefresh<T>(List<T> itemList)`? It's unclear though what you need to do with `itemList` or if you need some constraints for `T`.

Comment: I just want to manipulate the data that is passed i.e. 'if (item.Property ==..... etc '

Comment: But without a constraint, you don't have access to `item.Property` because you don't know the type of `item` at compile-time. This might even be an [XY Problem](https://xyproblem.info/) and it's better to [edit] the question and try to explain _exactly_ what you're trying to achieve so we can help you with it. Please make sure your code is a [repro].

Comment: Ive amended the idea in my mind. Does this help? Thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you need this:

```
public List<string> GetDataRefresh<T>(List<T> itemList)
{
    foreach (var item in itemList)
    {

    }
}
```

Comment: That did the trick...